# Show that for every $\epsilon > 0 $ there exists $h \in \mathcal{L}^1(X)$ non-negative and $\delta > 0$ such that:

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I am working through some practice questions, and I think I have gotten the first two parts, but I am having trouble deriving the third part:

> Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a finite measure space. Suppose that
>   $(f_k)$ is a sequence of measurable functions $X \rightarrow
> \mathbb{R}$ such that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $h \in
> \mathcal{L}^1(X)$ non-negative such that:
>
> $$ \int_{[|f_k|\ge h]} |f_k|d\mu< \epsilon$$
>
> for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Where $[|f_k|\ge h] = \{ x \in X : |f_k(x)| \ge h(x) \} $
>
> (1) Show that there exists $P>0$ such that:
>
> $$ \int_X |f_k|d\mu \le P$$ for all $k \in N$
>
> (2) Show that for every $A \in \mathcal{A}$ and every $h \in
> > \mathcal{L}^1(X)$ non-negative:
>
> $$ \int_A |f_n|d\mu \le \int_{[|f_k|\ge h]} |f_k|d\mu + \int_A h
> d\mu$$
>   (3) Using part (2), show that for every $\epsilon > 0 $ there exists $h \in 
>  \mathcal{L}^1(X)$ non-negative and $\delta > 0$ such that:
>
> $A \in \mathcal{A}$ and $\int_A h d\mu < \delta \implies \int_A |f_k|d
>  \mu < \epsilon $ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$

For part (1), I have written the integral on the left hand side as disjoint integrals, namely $ [|f_k|\ge h]$ and $[|f_k| < h]$ then the second integral is smaller than $\int_{[|f_k| < h]} h $, since it is precisely over the x's which $h > |f_k|$. And since we know the integrals of $h$ are finite, this yields the result.

For part (2), I have done a similar construction, splitting the problem into two cases, where $A$ and $[|f_k|\ge h]$ intersect and where they do not. I am able to derive the inequalities. Is this the right approach to this problem?

Part(3) is where I am having the most trouble, by part(2) it seems that I can immediately derive that $\int_A |f_k|d\mu < \epsilon + \delta $, but how to show it is just $< \epsilon$?

Any help would be very gratefully received!

Comment: What is $g$? What does $\in>$ mean?

Comment: sorry typos, should be $h$

Comment: Apply part 2, except with $\epsilon/2$ in place of epsilon. Now you have $\epsilon/2 + \delta$. If only $\delta$ were smaller than $\epsilon/2$. You can _make_ $\delta<\epsilon/2$ just by adding that to whatever other conditions you imposed on $\delta$...

Comment: hmm, what do you mean 'whatever other conditions you imposed on $\delta$'. Do you mean just say that I choose a $\delta < \epsilon /2 $? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes. If for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta$ such that $A<\delta$ implies $B<\epsilon$ then it follows that for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $\delta<\epsilon/2$ _and_ such that $A<\delta$ implies $B<\epsilon/2$.

Comment: Sorry David, I don't quite understand what you mean. Now given $ \epsilon $ I know that there is an $h$ such that $ \int_{[|f_k| \ge h]} |f_k| < \epsilon $, but then how can I construct a bounds on $h$? I'm not sure how I can draw any conclusions on $h$?

Comment: You _said_ you could do part 3 except you got $\epsilon+\delta$ instead of $\epsilon$. I was explaining how _if_ you got $\epsilon+\delta$ you automatically got $\epsilon$.

Comment: Sorry I did not write that very clearly. I don't really know how to do part 3, except that on the LHS of part 2, one integral I can choose to be bounded by $\epsilon$, and the other if $ < \delta $ provides a bound on $\int_A |f_k|d\mu $ - but I'm not sure how I can ensure $\int_A h d\mu < \delta$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part 3: Given $\epsilon>0$, there is $h$ such that 
$$
\int_{[|f_k|\ge h]} |f_k|d\mu< \epsilon
$$
For this $h$, by post [for each $\epsilon >0$ there is a $\delta >0$ such that whenever $m(A)<\delta$, $\int_A f(x)dx <\epsilon$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1357860/for-each-epsilon-0-there-is-a-delta-0-such-that-whenever-ma-delta/1357952#1357952),

given $\epsilon$, there is a $\eta$, for any $A$ such that $\mu(A)<\eta$,  there is
$$
\int_A h d\mu < \epsilon
$$
So
$$
\int_A |f_n|d\mu=\int_{A\cap [|f_n|\ge h]} |f_n|d\mu+\int_{A\cap [|f_n|< h]} |f_n|d\mu\leqslant \int_{[|f_n|\ge h]} |f_n|d\mu+\int_A h d\mu<2\epsilon
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So have you proved in another post that for any $ \epsilon $ there is $ \eta$ such that $\mu(A) < \eta \implies \int_A h d\mu < \epsilon $? I am trying to read that - but it's a bit hard to follow.

Comment: Yes, I proved it. It should not be too hard. This property is known as absolute continuity of Lebesgue integral.

Comment: I think I am starting to get it, so can I just confirm - $h$ is determined by our choice of $\epsilon$. But once we have our $h$, we can choose a second $ \epsilon $, which determines $\eta$ and whenever $\mu(A) < \eta $ then we have our result. So $A$ depends on $\eta$ which depends on $\epsilon$

Comment: Yes you got it Right

Answer (score 0):

This really should be a comment, but it's a bit too long.

Part 2 is very similar to part 1.
$$\begin{aligned}
\int_A|f_k| &= \int_{A \cap [|f_k| \geq h]}|f_k| + \int_{A \setminus [|f_k| \geq h]} |f_k| \\
&\leq \int_{A \cap [|f_k| \geq h]}|f_k| + \int_{A \setminus [|f_k| \geq h]} h \\
&\leq \int_{[|f_k| \geq h]}|f_k| + \int_{A} h
\end{aligned}$$
where the last inequality follows because the integrands are nonnegative and both sets increase from line 2 to line 3.