# Need help proving that $\int_{\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n}f{\rm d}\lambda = \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{E_n}f{\rm d}\lambda$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Here is the problem:  *If $f$ is a nonnegative Lebesgue measurable function* and $\{E_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of Lebesgue measurable sets with $E_1\subset E_2\subset ...$, then

$\int_{\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n}f{\rm d}\lambda = \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{E_n}f{\rm d}\lambda$.

I know that $\int_{\bigcup \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} E_{n}} f \,d\lambda = \int \limits_{\Bbb R} f \chi_{\bigcup \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} E_{n}} \,d\lambda$.

I'm also thinking that I should apply the Monotone Convergence Theorem.

However, I don't know where to go from here.
 Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not sure how to start proving that $\int_E f\,d\lambda$ = $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{E_n} f\,d\lambda$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2664336/not-sure-how-to-start-proving-that-int-e-f-d-lambda-lim-n-to-infty)

Comment: DO NOT ask the same question TWICE.

Comment: How could you not know it was already asked, when you asked the question I link, and ask it again here?:   NOT okay.

Comment: "Here is the following problem: Suppose that f is Lebesgue integrable over E and that $\{E_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of lebesgue measurable sets with $E_1$ $\subset$ $E_2$ $\subset$.... and $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} (E_{n})$ = E.  Prove that 

$\int_E f\,d\lambda$ = $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{E_n} f\,d\lambda$.

Any suggestions/ hints on how to start this problem would be appreciated."  Asked already by *you* [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2664336/not-sure-how-to-start-proving-that-int-e-f-d-lambda-lim-n-to-infty)

Comment: Hold up....these are two different questions. I simply thought you were referring to a different question (that was similar to this question) asked by someone else.

Comment: And I don't understand why my answer got downvote, is there mistake? So far I don't see there is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write $\displaystyle\int_{\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_{n}}fd\lambda=\int_{X}\chi_{\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_{n}}fd\lambda$ and $\displaystyle\int_{E_{n}}fd\lambda=\int_{X}\chi_{E_{n}}fd\lambda$ and now observe that $f\chi_{E_{n}}\uparrow f\chi_{\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_{n}}$ so Monotone Convergence Theorem applies here.

Comment: $f\chi_{E_{n}}\uparrow f\chi_{\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_{n}}$ follows since f is a nonnegative Lebesgue measurable function and $\{E_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a monotone nondecreasing sequence of Lebesgue measurable sets?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Alright. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What I like to do is think of this in terms of indicator/characteristic functions [like here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/907227/continuity-of-measure-and-integration-prove-int-af-d-mu-geq-0-implies).

I guess the measure space here is $(\Omega, \mathscr F, \lambda)$ with $\Omega = \mathbb R$ and $\mathscr F$ is Lebesgue-measurable sets (rather than [Borel sets or something](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1511031/why-do-we-consider-borel-sets-instead-of-measurable-sets)).

Let $E = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} E_n$. Then

1. $$\int_{\Omega} f1_{E_n}\,d\lambda = \int_{E_n} f\,d\lambda$$
2. $$\int_{\Omega} f 1_{E}\,d\lambda = \int_{E} f \,d\lambda$$

Now prove that

3. $$\lim f1_{E_n} = f1_E$$
4. $$f1_{E_n} \le f1_{E_{n+1}}$$

Next

5. By (3) and (4), monotone convergence theorem applies to let us say that

$$\lim \int_{\Omega} f1_{E_n}\,d\lambda = \int_{\Omega} \lim  f1_{E_n}\,d\lambda \tag{1}$$