# Prove that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_{[-n,n]} f\,d\lambda= \int f\,d\lambda.$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I am working on the following exercise:

> Let $\lambda$ denote Lebesgue measure on $\mathbf{R}$.  Suppose
>   $f:\mathbf{R}\rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ is a Borel measurable function
>   such that $\int|f|<\infty$.  Prove that  $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}
>  \int_{[-n,n]} f\,d\lambda= \int f\,d\lambda.$$

Now, I have some ideas as to things that could help me here, but I can't really put any of it together.  Here is what I have so far:

---

1. I know that, given a measure space $(X,\mathcal{S},\mu)$, a set $E\in \mathcal{S}$, and an $\mathcal{S}$-measurable function $f$, $$\int_E f\,d\mu=\int f\chi_{E}\,d\mu$$ if the RHS is defined.  In this case, I believe it is, since $\int |f|<\infty$.
2. Then [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2664336/not-sure-how-to-start-proving-that-int-e-f-d-lambda-lim-n-to-infty) got me thinking:  what if I write $[-n,n]$ as the limit of an increasing sequence of sets? That is, can I write $E=[-n,n]=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n$ where $E_n=[-n,n]$ for $n\in\mathbf{N}$?
3. If (2) is true, then I can define $f_n=f\chi_{E_n}$ and $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n=f\chi_E.$$  Then I think I would have my answer by the Dominated Convergence Theorem.

---

Am I on the right track here?

Comment: Yes, and you're pretty much done.

Comment: @T.Bongers Really?  Well that is certainly a relief.  If I may ask an additional question in regards to my second step.  Did I set that up right?  For whatever reason I am having a hard time convincing myself that what I wrote is true, i.e. that $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n=[-n,n]$.  I tried drawing a picture, but it made me think -- shouldn't $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n=(-\infty,\infty)$?

Comment: It is $(-\infty, \infty)$, but don't you want it to be? You're integrating over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is fine as-is.

---

For an alternative proof, you could apply the monotone convergence theorem to the sequences $f^+ \chi_{E_n}$ and $f^{-} \chi_{E_n}$ separately.