# If $f$ is absolutely integrable, then for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ s.t. $\int_A f\,d\mu < \epsilon$ whenever $\mu(A) < \delta$

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Is this valid on $\mathbb R^n$ when $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure? What about on arbitrary measure spaces?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: This has been asked and answered many times before. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1357860/for-each-epsilon-0-there-is-a-delta-0-such-that-whenever-ma-delta?rq=1 for example.